# Getting Fatal error: Call to a member function query() on a non object error while including database details twice

Tags: php

I have 3 files in my program those are database.php ,index.php,functions.php
When I click next button of dashboard.php file it shows these two errors.

> Notice: Undefined variable: conn in C:\wamp\www\quiz\functions.php on line 144
>
> Fatal error: Call to a member function query() on a non-object in C:\wamp\www\quiz\functions.php on line 41

Line number 144 is `$result = $conn->query($sql);` when I replace `include_once('database.php');`line of `getQuizes_answer1()` function with the content of the database.php file it works fine.
Is there anyone who can clarify why this is happening like this?

this is how my functions.php file looks like

```
function getQuizes($quizNo)
{
    if($quizNo==NULL)
    {
        $quizNo=0;
    }
    require('database.php');
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM quiz LIMIT ".$quizNo.",1";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);
    while($row=$result->fetch_assoc())
    {
        echo $row['question'];
    }
    $quizNo++;
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM quiz";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);
    $rowcount=mysqli_num_rows($result);

    if($quizNo>=$rowcount)
    {
        $quizNo=0;
    }
    return $quizNo;
}

function getQuizes_answer1($quizNo)
{
    include_once('database.php');
    if($quizNo!=0)
    {
        $quizNo--;
    }
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM quiz LIMIT ".$quizNo.",1";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);
    while($row=$result->fetch_assoc())
    {
        echo $row['answer1'];
    }
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM quiz";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);
    $rowcount=mysqli_num_rows($result);
    if($quizNo>=$rowcount)
    {
        $quizNo=0;
    }
$conn->close();
}
```

This is how my dashboard.php file looks like

```
<?php
    $i = isset($_SESSION['next']) ? $_SESSION['next'] : NULL;
    if(isset($_POST['next']))
    {
        $i = getQuizes($i);
        $_SESSION['next'] = $i;
 ?>
 <div class="answers_block">
     <table>
                <tr>
                    <td><?php getQuizes_answer1($i);?></td>
                </tr>
     </table>
 </div>
     <?php
     }
     ?>
       <form method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">
           <input name="next" value="Next" type="submit" />
       </form>
```

my database.php file looks like this

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$database="quiz_db";
// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $database);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is, your connection handler `$conn` is not available in the scope of your function. Either use `global` or pass the connection handler as an argument to your function.

**Method(1):**

```
function getQuizes($quizNo){
    global $conn;

    // your code
}

function getQuizes_answer1($quizNo){
    global $conn;

    // your code
}
```

**Method(2):**

```
function getQuizes($conn, $quizNo){

    // your code

}

function getQuizes_answer1($conn, $quizNo){

    // your code

}
```

Comment: But when I'm using only getQuizes() method i don't need to add 
global $conn;
 it works fine. But when I'm using getQuizes_answer1();  method with getQuizes(); method  I need to add  this global $conn; can you clarify it little bit for me .

Comment: @isuruAbey That's because in *getQuizes()* method,  you're doing `require('database.php');`, which makes the connection handler available in the scope of the function. But in *getQuizes_answer1()* method you're not doing anything as such.

Comment: are these the only way to prevent this problem. I have used `include()` instead of `required()` both are give same error,

Comment: @isuruAbey Yes, you can include the connection file inside the function to make it work, but it's a good programming practice to pass the connection handler to the function as a parameter. Have you tested your application with the methods I suggested?

Comment: Thanks for your answers and clear clarification. It works fine,

Comment: @isuruAbey Glad I could help. :-)